# VS 2012 updating all my .sln?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I've got VS 2012 installed and I feel like it's taking over EVERY solution on my freakin hard drive.  Meaning it's converting the solution it seems to VS 2012 automatically.  OR at least all my .sln icons are showing version 11 and the VS 2012 solution icon.  WHY????

I did not convert these.  What's going on?  I've seen this happen on all my PCs.  Now I can't open any solution file that was lets say versioned in VS 2010 or prior because it looks like they all get converted automatically?  I'm confused, this is odd.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on this but I found some info.

I don't believe the projects will be converted automatically, but .sln files will as default be opened by VS 2012.

But maybe the project upgrade Wizard changes the files directly before asking you to do it?

[vs-2012-project-file-compatibility-with-vs-2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20160219000257/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/thunbrynt/archive/2012/06/12/vs-2012-project-file-compatibility-with-vs-2010.aspx)

[Visual Studio 2012 Compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh266747%28v=vs.110%29)